# How to initialize multiple keys with same value in python

Tags: python

So, I have this issue where I want to add multiple keys to a dict.

So, I have something like this

```
all_vals_dict = {}
for key in keys:
     some_response = fetch(key) # returns a list
     d = dict.fromKeys(some_response, key)
     all_vals_dict = {**d, **all_vals}
```

But what I want is that all_vals_dict, the value to be set rather than "key". For example..

lets say keys = [1,2]
when key = 1

```
some_response = ['foo', 'bar']
d = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 1}
all_vals_dict = {'foo': 1, 'bar':1}
```

when key = 2

```
some_response = ['foo', 'baz']
d = {'foo': 2, 'baz': 2}
all_vals_dict = {'foo': 2, 'bar':1, 'baz':2}
```

Instead of the above.. what i want is
after first iteration:

```
all_vals_dict = {'foo': {1}, 'bar': {1}}
```

after second iteration:

```
all_vals_dict = {'foo': {1, 2}, 'bar': {1}, 'baz':{2}}
```

Comment: can `baz` also be a set?

Comment: @MasonCaiby ah yes.. that's a typo.. it should be set. let me fix that.

Comment: Should `all_vals` be `all_vals_dict`?

Comment: @Barmar good catch.. yes

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the strings in `some_response`. For each of them, check if it already exists as a key in the dictionary. If it does, add to the set, otherwise initialize it with a new set.

There doesn't seem to be much point in the `d` dictionary.

```
all_vals_dict = {}
for key in keys:
    some_response = fetch(key) # returns a list
    for label in some_response:
        if label in all_vals_dict:
            all_vals_dict[label].add(key)
        else:
            all_vals_dict[label] = {key}
```